# Multi peer connection in webrtc

Tags: javascript

I use array `pc` to save RTCPeerConnections from 1 client to other clients then call `createOffer`.

`pc` is global variable but have an error:  inside createOffer function, I get `pc[list[i]]` is `undefined`. How do I fix it?

```
for (var i = 0; i<list.length - 1; i++) {
    pc[list[i]] = createPC(list[i]);
    pc[list[i]].createOffer(function (localDesc) {
        pc[list[i]].setLocalDescription(localDesc);
        send(localDesc, list[i]);
    }, doNothing, constraints);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

must be the usual problem with callbacks inside for loop, try binding the value of `i`:

```
for (var i = 0; i<list.length - 1; i++) {
    pc[list[i]] = createPC(list[i]);
    (function(i){
        pc[list[i]].createOffer(function (localDesc) {
            pc[list[i]].setLocalDescription(localDesc);
            send(localDesc, list[i]);
        }, doNothing, constraints);
    })(i);
}
```

Edit:

another option might be( i am assuming that the list is list of unique ids):

```
...
for (var i = 0; i<list.length - 1; i++) {
    var id = list[i];
    pc[id] = createPC(id);
    pc[id].createOffer(onOffer.bind({id:id}), doNothing, constraints);
}
...
function onOffer(localDesc){
    pc[this.id].setLocalDescription(localDesc);
    send(localDesc, this.id);
}
```